# Insert string into expression

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my script user has to specify directions and I have to execute my code according to this direction. My only idea is:

```
function (dir) {
  var element = document.querySelector('#id');
  eval('element.style. ' + dir + ' = 10\'px'\;'
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way for doing this. Because as I know eval is not a good practice.

Comment: Leaving aside `eval` being the wrong tool (accepted answer has correct solution), it's worth noting that `element.style.left = 10'px';` wouldn't be valid code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without error checking to make sure `element.style[dir]` exists, you can do this:

```
function foo(dir) {
  var element = document.querySelector('#id');
  element.style[dir] = '10px';
}
```

I'm going to assume you'd be using it like this:

```
foo('top'); // ==>  element.style.top = '10px';
```